# Force variable height DIV below variable height DIV

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a 2 horizontal part menu bar, each with a different background color.

The top bar has a menu system that will wrap if the screen is too small.

The second bar has an image and search bar.

The top bar needs to auto-size based on how many rows of options exist.

Currently the second bar's contents show up (image/search), however the background and DIV element are under the main bar.

```
<div id="header_nav_buttons" style="position:absolute">
    <ul>
        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="link1" runat="server"/></li>
        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="link2" runat="server"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="sub_header">        
    <div id="logo">
        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="img_Logo" ImageAlign="Left" Width="173px" />
    </div>
    <div id="search_bar">
        <input name="search_input" runat="server" type="text" id="search_input" style="margin-right: 20px;" maxlength="50" />
        <asp:Button ID="btn_Search" runat="server" Text="Search" CssClass="form_save_button" OnClick="search_go_Click" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Search_Box_Subtext" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header_nav_buttons
{
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    float: left;

    width: 100%;
    background-color:#6690BF;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 30px;
    bottom: auto;
}

#header_nav_buttons ul
{
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
}

#header_nav_buttons li
{
    display: inline-flex;
    padding-right: 13px;    
}

#sub_header
{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #e5ecf4;    
}

#logo
{
    width:173px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

#search_bar
{
    right:20px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    float: right;
}
```

To add to the confusion, in #search_bar, if I remove float:right then some of the background shows up (while still starting too high, under the main header bar color).

Comment: I think you have to remove inline style of main div.
And for the second header(#sub_header) use width:100%;float:left as well so it will also gets wrapped

#sub_header{
width:100%;float:left;
}

Comment: @VarshaDhadge the inline style is part of the UL element, and i need that along with the inline-flex in the IL element, to get the DIV to expand around the menu bar.

However as a test I just removed it and I still have the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this through some random attempts.

I added float:left to the #sub_header CSS section, and it solved the issue,

Comment: Isn't solution provided in above comment says to apply float left to an element to make it work

Comment: @VarshaDhadge My apologies, I totally overlooked that part of your comment earlier.